# Maximum value of $\lambda$

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is given that a,b,c are be of same sign and a,b,c are in Harmonic progression i.e. $\frac{2}{b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}$ and also
 $\frac{a+b}{2a-b}+\frac{c+b}{2c-b}\geq \sqrt{\lambda \sqrt{\lambda \sqrt{\lambda.............\infty}}}$.

Find the greatest possible value of $\lambda$.

How should I begin? I think we somehow need to find value of R.H.S. when equality holds but how to achieve that? Also using the result $b=\frac{2ac}{a+c}$ doesn't give any fruitful result.

Comment: Doesn't the RHS converge to $\lambda$?

Comment: @Mathematics Okay, but the RHS is still $\lambda$.

Comment: @OliverJones Yes we need maximum value of $\lambda$. Can you suggest something?

Comment: @Mathematics I don't understand. If the RHS is $\lambda$, isn't the maximum value the LHS?

Comment: @OliverJones $\lambda \leq$ Some quantity, so maximum value value of $\lambda$ will be achieved when it is equal to that quantity.

Comment: @Mathematics I can't understand you at all. Your question seems badly worded. For example, why write that limit if it's just $\lambda$?

Comment: @OliverJones Rearrange $\frac{2}{b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}$ and you will get $b=\frac{2ac}{a+c}$. You not understanding it does not make it badly worded. In questions we have to deduce something. So if R.H.S. converges to $\lambda$ so be it but why write it straightaway.

Comment: @OliverJones - "why write that limit if it's just $\lambda$/" - indeed. Why do textbook ask questions like $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n^2 = ?$ when they could have just written $ \pi^2/6 = ?$ It's like they expect you work it out yourself or something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=1/x,\; b=1/y, \;c=1/z.$ We have $y=(x+z)/2$. The LHS of the inequality is $$\frac {y+x}{2 y-x}+\frac  {y+z}{2 y-z}=\frac { z/2+ 3 x/2}{z}+\frac { x/2+ 3 z/2}{x}=1+\frac {3}{2} (x/z+z/x).$$ Since $x$ and $z$ (which are $1/a$ and $1/c$) have the same sign, $x/z$ and $z/x$ are positive, so $$x/z+z/x=(\;(x/z)^{1/2}- (z/x)^{1/2}\;)^2+2\geq 2.$$ Therefore $1+\frac {3}{2}(x/z+z/x)\geq 1+\frac{3}{2}(2)=4.$ Equality occurs here iff $a=b=c.$

Comment: So you're just finding a lower bound for $\frac{a+b}{2a-b}+\frac{c+b}{2c-b}$ subject to the condition that $a,b,$ and $c$ are of the same sign and are in harmonic progression. The limit on the right hand side is irrelevant.

Comment: @Oliver Jones .As far as I can tell, the Q is to find the glb for the LHS given the conditions on a,b,c. The glb is 4, so the greatest possible value for $\lambda $ is 4.